# How to monitor the frequency of processes writing to a file on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, io, system-monitoring

Just wondering if there is a way (tool/script) to monitor, similar to the way the "top" command monitors processes, the write operations performed by process to a file, especially log files.

AFAIK that "fuser" could be a candidate when put in a sleep-n-continue loop but there's a chance that the write operation might not last long enough for the "fuser" to capture. Or is there a way to address that issue?

Desired pseudo-output:

```
 PID    # of writes    bytes written
 2048       33             31280
 2049       31             23244
```

Comment: _Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)._

Comment: Why is this question on hold? There's nothing general about it and it's clear what user needs/wants from the description + example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find [iotop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) and [fatrace](https://launchpad.net/fatrace) useful to help you achieve what you want.

Comment: fatrace is exactly what i need. Thank you! :)